# raise_application error not working in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

I have been trying PL/SQL for quite some time now and I've tried creating a procedure and a trigger but I'm unable to get the required output. Let me share what I've done till now.

```
==> create or replace procedure cast(act_id movie_cast.act_id%TYPE, mov_id movie_cast.mov_id%TYPE, role movie_cast.role%TYPE)
        IS
        begin
        insert into movie_cast values(act_id, mov_id, role);
        end;
        /
        
        Procedure created.
        
==>> SQL> create or replace trigger trg1
          2  before insert on movie_cast
          3  for each row
          4  declare
          5  num number;
          6  begin
          7  select count(act_id) into num from movie_cast where mov_id = :new.mov_id;
          8  if(:old.mov_id = :new.mov_id AND :old.act_id = :new.act_id) then
          9  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Actor already in the movie!');
         10  end if;
         11  end;
         12  /
        
        Trigger created.
```

I've customize the error in line number 9 and I'm not getting the error there. Like when I'm fullfilling this condition==> if(:old.mov_id = :new.mov_id AND :old.act_id = :new.act_id), I want an error but I'm not getting it.
Can anybody help me with it?
Thank you so much!

SQL> select * from movie_cast;

```
ACT_ID     MOV_ID ROLE
```

---

```
   101        901 John Scottie Ferguson
   102        902 Miss Giddens
   103        903 T. E. Lawrence
   104        904 Michael
   105        905 Antonio Salieri
   106        906 Rick Deckard
   107        907 Alice Harford
   108        908 McManus
   109        909 J. J. Gittes
   110        910 Eddie Adams
   111        911 Alvy Singer
   112        912 San
   113        913 Adny Dufresne
   114        914 Lester Burnham
   115        915 Rose DeWitt Bukater
   116        916 Sean Maguire
   117        917 Ed
   118        918 Renton
   119        919 Alfred Borden
   120        920 Elizabeth Darko
   121        921 Older Jamal
   122        922 Ripley
   114        923 Bobby Darin
   122        922 dummy
```

24 rows selected.

PS: This is the movie_cast table and I want to insert act_id and mov_id there, the condition for trigger is you cannot cast same actor for same movie twice but you can cast an actor for different movies.

Comment: i dont really know what u wanted to do here, but this exception wont be raised because when you are inserting data, there is no :old row values. You are inserting this row, and you are in before insert trigger. :old values would be aviable for example in: before update trigger, but forsure not in before insert trigger. And even if it compiles, you will have null values there. You are doing count on table that you are inserting row- most likely it will cause problems signalized by mutating table error. What is more, you dont even use that count in any place further, why you did that then?

Comment: Can you plz look-in, this time I've updated the question for more clarity?

Answer (score 1):

That's a wrong approach.

A row-level trigger on `movie_cast` that selects from the same table will raise a mutating table error.

Correct way to do that is to create unique index (or unique / primary key constraint) on those columns, e.g.

```
create unique index on movie_cast (mov_id, act_id);
```

Comment: Can you plz look-into the question? I've updated it.

Comment: Nothing changes in my answer, I'm afraid. It is the unique index you need.

Comment: SQL> create unique index ind1 on movie_cast(act_id, mov_id);
create unique index ind1 on movie_cast(act_id, mov_id)
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found

Comment: There are already repetitive values in act_id! #114 is repeating...

Comment: ... which means that you FIRST have to sort that out (remove duplicates), and then create unique index.

Comment: No but there will be actors doing more than 1 movie like #114 here. So, there will be repetitive values. We just need look for actor not to be casted in a movie more than once.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand what I'm saying. There must be unique combination of [actor, movie]. To enforce that, create unique index on those two columns. Currently, you can not do that because duplicates already exist in the table. For example, you have two rows with [Tom Hanks, Terminal] column values. You have to delete all duplicates (and leave only one of them). Once you fix that, you'll be able to create unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question- :old values are null in before trigger, thats why your condition will be never fullfilled, never ever- even if you insert row with nulls, null=null condition wont pass, null is null is TRUE, but null = null will give you FALSE, atleast for Oracle DB.